# finding points of discontinuity of the function $f(x) = \frac{\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x+1}}{ \frac{1}{x-1} - \frac{1}{x}}$.

Tags: calculus, continuity

finding points of discontinuity of the function $f(x) = \frac{\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x+1}}{ \frac{1}{x-1} - \frac{1}{x}}$.

**My answer is:**

After simplifying the function it becomed $$f(x) = \frac{x-1}{x+1}$$ and I found that the function is undefined at $x = -1$ and limit $f(x)$ as x tends to (-1) is $-\infty$, hence the function has essential discontinuity at this point.

Am I correct?

Comment: Original function is not defined at $x=0,1$ as well. So those are also possible points of discontinuity.

Comment: How the original function is not defined at those points ...... could you explain please?@AnuragA

Comment: You have $1/x$ and $1/x-1$ appearing in your **original** function (not the one you got after simplification). The *simplified* function and your original function coincide at all points except $x=0,\pm1$. For example, the function $f(x)=\frac{x}{x}$ and $g(x)=1$ coincide at all $x \in \mathbb{R}-\{0\}$.

Comment: @AnuragA look at the second answer below it says that $x=1$ is not a point of discontionuity .... do you have a justification?

Comment: I disagree with his finding. $x=1$ is not in the domain of the original function and is a point of discontinuity of the original function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algebra has allowed you to change the formula of the function, simplifying it.

But there was a cost: not only did you change the formula, *you changed the function itself*. Before applying the algebra and changing the formula, it is clear from the formula that plugging in $x=0$ and $x=1$ and $x=-1$ lead to zeroes in denominators which make no sense. So those three values of $x$ are *not in the domain*. After changing the formula, you can still see that $x=-1$ is not in the domain, but those algebraic alterations have hidden an important reality: you *still* cannot plug $x=0$ and $x=1$ into the *original formula* for the function.

Comment: the answer below said that 1 can be plugged in the original function could you justify this please?

Answer (score 1):

we have to take two term into account,they are $\frac{1}{x},\frac{1}{x+1}$
to be defined at those points it is necessary to $x\ne0$ and $x\ne-1$
you can also think,why am I not taking  $\frac{1}{x-1}$ part into account.Let's see,
if $x\to1$,then the function becomes like $$\lim_{k\to \infty}\dfrac{something}{k}=0$$
so,it doesn't affect the function.so,for the original function the points of discontinuity are $x=-1,0$

**NOTE:** if you simplify the function then you are removing the removable discontinuous points.the function has a removable discontinuity at point $x=0$.

Comment: and a removable continuity at 1 ....correct?

Comment: no.it has a zero point at $x=1$.

Comment: what do you mean by a zero point

Comment: So you are saying that the point $x = 1$ is in the domain of the function.... correct?

Comment: yes.$x=1$ stays in that domain.

Comment: This is incorrect. The domain of the function is all values of $x$ that can be plugged into the original formula for the function, so $x=1$ is not in the domain of the original function. By simplifying the formula you are *altering* the function by changing its domain: the new domain is the union of the two sets: the old domain; and the set $\{1\}$.